# Accessing modem FTP Server with WAN IP

Tags: ip, ftp, wan

I have configured the FTP server on my router. The FTP server IP address is 192.168.1.1 (same as routers IP address). I port forwarded Port-Forward setup image. Locally FTP server works like charm with ftp://192.168.1.1 and ftp://46.239.xxx.xxx (WAN IP), but when I want to use my server when I'm on a different network through WAN IP it doesn't connect.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps the FTP server limits remote connections for security. You might want to look at the settings on your router and see if there are any that may be blocking those connections.

Answer (score 0):

FTP requires a large number of extra ports to function correctly.   it doesn't forward well. to forward it successfully you need FTP aware forwarding rules.

you could perhaps setup the router as the DMZ server (where all ports with no explicit rules connect) but that seems like a major security risk.

maybe you can use HTTP of SFTP instead.